# Is it possible to get Analytics Report for date: previous month?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I have created a GA report in the Google Spreadsheets.  I want to import data for the previous month, but I can only set the range of dates or the number of the days.
Is it possible to set the date as a “previous month” (using filter or regular expression ...).
There is no such parameter as  “previous month” in the API.

Comment: See the [Dimensions and metrics explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) for the full set of available dimensions and metrics.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only relative dates expressions are:

> today, yesterday or NdaysAgo

But please tell us more about on how you make the queries from GA to SpreadSheets. If you are using Google Apps Script or python for example you can get relative dates as a variable and add them to the query.

Comment: I'm new at Google Scripts, so I do it with Add-ons, using Analitycs API. [link](http://clip2net.com/s/3QuQoIq)

Comment: The Analytics API Add-on is really useful but your are trying to get too specific so i would recommend you to look into python since its really easy as a language and google SDK is friendly.

Comment: Thank you!
Maybe you can recommend some sources for studying?

Comment: @KristyTanskaya Checkout the [Quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py)